# How to fetch data with useEffect and then render based on selected filter option in React Js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am fetching the data using useEffect then want to later change or update table based on filter selection but the problem is it's exactly rendering what I am selecting from filter instead it's rendering previous selected option data. for example if I select pending from filter first then resolved it will render pending on selection on resolved.

I don't know where I am making mistakes.

**QueryView.js**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const QueriesView = () => {
    const [queryData, setqueryData] = useState([])
    const [status, setStatus] = useState("Pending")
    const [data,setdata] = useState([])

    const getStatus = (e) => {
        setStatus(e.target.value)

        setdata( queryData.filter(ele=> ele.querystatus === status))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        let url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbykZx2qtz39U5j8TwDRVuziKfoLzF6YkYvDL6Ejoj822Vg9MPe1pDS9PX86IeP1Kzw82Q/exec?request=getQueriesData";
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(url);
                const json = await response.json();
                setqueryData(json)
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log("catching error")
            }
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [])


    return (
        <>       
            <div className='container mt-2'>
            <div className='row'>
                <select className="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example"
                name='status'
                onChange={getStatus}
                value={status.value}
                >
                    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                    <option value="Resolved">Resolved</option>
                    <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Date</th>
                            <th scope="col">Query Number</th>
                            <th scope="col">Email</th>
                            <th scope="col">Full Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Phone No.</th>
                            <th scope="col">Status</th>
                            <th scope="col">Details</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {data.map(ele => (
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">{ele.querydate}</th>
                                <td>{ele.querynumber}</td>
                                <td>{ele.email}</td>
                                <td>{ele.firstname} {ele.lastname}</td>
                                <td>{ele.contact}</td>
                                <td>{ele.querystatus}</td>
                                <td><button type='button'>Details</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default QueriesView;
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
When the data is fetched in the `useEffect`, it must be filtered again according to the currently selected status:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    let url =
      "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbykZx2qtz39U5j8TwDRVuziKfoLzF6YkYvDL6Ejoj822Vg9MPe1pDS9PX86IeP1Kzw82Q/exec?request=getQueriesData";
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const json = await response.json();
        setqueryData(json);
        // set filtered again
        setdata(json.filter((ele) => ele.querystatus === status));
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("catching error");
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-stitch-k11sdd?file=/src/QueriesView.js

---

When using `.map()` to render a list of items, you always must provide a key so React can identify the corresponding entries: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

For example using the array index (another field than index would better):

```
{data.map((ele, index) => (
    <tr key={index}>
            <th scope="row">{ele.querydate}</th>
            <td>{ele.querynumber}</td>
            <td>{ele.email}</td>
            <td>{ele.firstname} {ele.lastname}</td>
            <td>{ele.contact}</td>
            <td>{ele.querystatus}</td>
            <td><button type='button'>Details</button></td>
    </tr>
))}
```

Comment: but problem is not rendering right now i have trouble with how to render data in table based on value selected from filter that the main issue which is not working here could you check the code and let me know the answer

Comment: @KuldeepSingh please see my updated answer

Comment: I havae checked my problem is not what you mentioning it working same without index key problem  when you select any option from filter like pending or rejected then only pending or rejected entries should be render which is not happening right now

Comment: @KuldeepSingh I know, see the update in my answer. After the fetching the data, it must be filtered inside the useEffect hook.